# Sprokets on rotating body

Tags: gears, mechanisms

Sorry I'm having a migrane and can't think rn, which is why I am posting such a basic question for confirmation...

[image: Sprockets on rotating beam]

The above diagram shows two sprockets on a beam which is attached to a driven gear.
The Red sprocket doesn't rotate (it is fixed). The orange sprocket is at the other end of the beam and can spin freely. Theres a chain between them (not drawn)

Relative to the gear/beam, the red sprocket is rotating in reverse.

So would I be correct in saying that the orange sprocket will turn with the opposite angular velocity of the Driven Gear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sprockets have the same number of teeth both the red and orange sprockets will remain in the same relative orientation. The writing on the orange will remain horizontal.

If red has *N* teeth then the chain will advance *N* links per rotation. If orange has *n* teeth then it will rotate *N/n* teeth relative to the red.

So rotating the beam one revolution clockwise will result in the the orange sprocket rotating anti-clockwise relative to the beam by N/n turns.

Comment: so if I attach a beam to the orange Sprocket at a specific angle, it will stay at that angle (relative to the ground) no matter how the diven gear is rotated correct?

Comment: @Ankrit:  provided that the sprockets have the same number of teeth (which also means that the should be the the same size)/